# Encoding UTF-8 with Go

Tags: c#, go

I am trying to find the equivalent of the following C# code in Go.

```
pwd = "abc123";
encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(text));
```

I know that there is a [crypto/sha1](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha1/) package within Go. I know I can run:

```
pwd := "abc123"
hasher := sha1.New() // SHA1.Create();
hasher.Write([]byte(pwd)) // sha1.ComputeHash but without encoding in UTF8 ?
```

I am not sure how I can get the correct encoding when hashing. I was wondering if I could get some help converting this

Comment: Go strings are utf8 encoded. You only need to re-encode if you need another encoding. (this is also not encryption, nor is the fact you're hashing bytes relevant to string encoding)

Comment: @JimB, that's not correct: strings in Go are opaque collections of bytes. String *literals* indeed provide UTF-8-encoded strings because the Go source files are defined to be encoded in UTF-8. The other case where Go strings are *interpreted* as being encoded in UTF-8 is iterating over Unicode code points *(runes)* in them using the `range` statement. Full details are in the must read [Go blog entry on strings](http://blog.golang.org/strings).

Comment: @kostix: yes, maybe I should have said "interpreted" or assumed to be utf8 when converting to runes, as the string representation is obviously just a series of bytes.

Comment: @JimB, I know your skill level is high; just did the usual nitpicking. I think we should strive not to create a wrong mental model in the mind of a newfangled gopher, so felt the need to chime in ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> A string literal, absent byte-level escapes, always holds valid UTF-8
>   sequences.

So you don't need to encode into utf8 the string if is inside the Golang source code. However, if the string comes from an input, the [utf8](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/) package is your friend.