# How to convert utf8 string to []byte?

Tags: json, string, go, type-conversion, slice

I want to unmarshal a `string` that contains JSON,
however the `Unmarshal` function takes a `[]byte` as input.

How can I convert my UTF8 `string` to `[]byte`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40384408/1975086
You do `[]byte(s)`

Comment: Already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032170/how-to-assign-string-to-bytes-array

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This question is a possible duplicate of [How to assign string to bytes array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032170/how-to-assign-string-to-bytes-array), but still answering it as there is a better, alternative solution:

Converting from `string` to `[]byte` is allowed by the spec, using a simple [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

> **Conversions to and from a string type**
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Converting a value of a string type to a slice of bytes type yields a slice whose successive elements are the bytes of the string.

So you can simply do:

```
s := "some text"
b := []byte(s) // b is of type []byte
```

However, the `string => []byte` conversion makes a copy of the string content (it has to, as `string`s are immutable while `[]byte` values are not), and in case of large `string`s it's not efficient. Instead, you can create an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) using [`strings.NewReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader) which will read from the passed `string` without making a copy of it. And you can pass this `io.Reader` to [`json.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) and unmarshal using the [`Decoder.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode) method:

```
s := `{"somekey":"somevalue"}`

var result interface{}
err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(s)).Decode(&result)
fmt.Println(result, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oWn4n5Pqpw)):

```
map[somekey:somevalue] <nil>
```

Note: calling `strings.NewReader()` and `json.NewDecoder()` does have some overhead, so if you're working with small JSON texts, you can safely convert it to `[]byte` and use [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal), it won't be slower:

```
s := `{"somekey":"somevalue"}`

var result interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &result)
fmt.Println(result, err)
```

Output is the same. Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fBs4Hf6_Mt).

Note: if you're getting your JSON input `string` by reading some `io.Reader` (e.g. a file or a network connection), you can directly pass that `io.Reader` to `json.NewDecoder()`, without having to read the content from it first.

Comment: Another great post that I have quoted. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546

Answer (score 1):

just use []byte(s) on the string. for example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := `{"test":"ok"}`
    var data map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &data); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("json data: %v", data)
}
```

check it out on the playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/F_MRLXf3Fz).